# How to solve 'problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.'?

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies, imagepicker

I was running my flutter application, when suddenly my computer shut down due to low battery. When restarted and wanted to run the program, I encountered this problem:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.
> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.5\android\build.gradle' from cache.
```

I try to delete gradle/cache/7.4 but its not working. anyone know how to fix this, or why this is happening?

Edit:
After i do some research, i find that this was caused by `image_picker` plugin in my dependency. But still don't know how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache is usually at the following locations.

`On Windows: %USERPROFILE%\.gradle\caches`

`On Mac / UNIX: ~/.gradle/caches/`

Removing the whole .gralde folder is safe, Unless you have some global properties which are `gradle.properties` file then it's a good idea to keep it.

You can try as well to clean build cache, with the following command `gradlew cleanBuildCache`.

Comment: I try all that, but it's not working